# How would I use Background Worker to get my GUI to respond?

Tags: c#

I made a short program which has just a button. When the button is pressed, functionA is executed, which also uses functionB and functionC. Inside functionA is a loop which executes functionB and functionC X amount of times. At the end of each loop, the progressbar gets incremented by 1. At the beginning of functionA, before the loop, there's a webservice which pulls data from a website, and passes that onto B and C for processing (data file manipulation and saving to disk).

My problem is that everything works fine, but while functionA is still running, the GUI is stuck, so I can't close/minimize/drag the window around, I have to wait until A is done. I researched and they say I should use BackgroundWorker, but as being a new programmer, I've no idea on how to use it. Can someone give me a simple way to use it?

The progressbar loads fine, but it's just that while the function is running, the whole window is frozen, and I want it so I can move the window around, etc while the program is running, instead of waiting until the function is complete.

Thank you!

Comment: Start by posting the code you have already. Describing it is not really what's expected here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: Go read [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or [How to: Use a Background Worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there. This question format is not appropriate for SO. SO is appropriate for more specific questions with code segments. Try this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: You may use the [SxProgress class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829395/an-easy-to-use-progress-bar-for-winforms). You must just isolate the code of function A loop in a procedure. If you want, you may minimize your form before calling SxProgress, then the progress pop-up form will be the only visible part of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Call your function asynchronously like the following and it will not freeze the UI.

```
private async void BeginProcessingAsync(Data d)
{
    //Execute the long running task asynchronously
    await Task.Run(() =>  functionA(d));

    //Anything after the await line will be executed only after the task is finished.
    anotherFunction(d); // if you have one..
}
```

To run your task, simply call `BeginProcessingAsync(d);`. Also, please note: If you're using newer versions of .NET, you might have to use `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => functionA(d));` instead of the above

Answer (score 0):

Overall, you'll want to make sure your GUI doesn't get updated from another thread. Instead, the messages should go to a threadsafe location. *For instance*, you could have the thread building into something like a database and have the GUI using a timer to look for updated data flags.

There is a question with a lot [more detail using delegates here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c).

[Marc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) answer was the simplest and best, in my opinion:

```
///...blah blah updating files
string newText = "abc"; // running on worker thread
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    someLabel.Text = newText; // runs on UI thread
});
///...blah blah more updating files
```

From **Dotnet Perls**:

> A [Background Worker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) makes threads easy to implement in Windows
>   Forms. Intensive tasks need to be done on another thread so the UI
>   does not freeze. It is necessary to post messages and update the user
>   interface when the task is done.

Also, from **MSDN**, look at [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) (TAP) if you're using C# 5.

> The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) is based on the
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task and System.Threading.Tasks.Task
>   types in the System.Threading.Tasks namespace, which are used to
>   represent arbitrary asynchronous operations. TAP is the recommended
>   asynchronous design pattern for new development.